# eval in javascript runs bad method

Tags: javascript, eval

In this code eval function is used:
[image: code1]

function in string has 3 params, but eval runs function with 2 params:

[image: code2]

Why ?

Comment: Please don't use images of code, instead copy/paste the text of the code into the body of your question.

Comment: You've defined openURL twice. The second one ends up being the only one that's accessible

Comment: There is no **function overloading** in javascript. The second function overwrites the first, so you end up with only one `openURL` function that takes two parameters.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot have 2 functions with the same name in the same scope.

There is no function overloading in javascript. (thanks ibrahim mahrir).

Delete the `openURL` function that starts on line 5317.

**2019 Edit:**
It is possible to call different methods based on the number of arguments: pattern:
https://johnresig.com/apps/learn/#90